# How do I select a custom port to connect to when using PuTTY through WinSCP

Tags: windows, ssh, telnet, putty, winscp

WinSCP offers a great option to connect via PuTTY with one button. The only problem, is there is no way to set the port which PuTTY connects to. So if my server uses a custom port (1024), I have to load PuTTY manually and do this connection.

I know WinSCP has some command line parameters that help set this up, listed here: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#session_configuration but I tried adding -p 1024 to the PuTTY.exe path, but it gave me an error

> unknown option -p

When I load putty.exe separately I can see a `WinSCP Temporary Session Configuration` is present in the list. It is set to port 23. When I change this to port 1024 and save, I can log in via telnet by pressing `open`.

However, when I try to click on the PuTTY button in WinSCP again, it is still unable to connect. And when I open putty.exe the next time, it shows WinSCP Temporary Session is reset back to port 23.

If anyone has a suggestion how I can connect to a custom port through PuTTY when using WinSCP, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's in Options->Prefernces->Applications, use path

"%ProgramFiles%\PuTTY\putty.exe" -P 1024

Answer (score 0):

While you can change a global configuration, like your own answer shows, it breaks a connection to all other sessions/servers, which use a standard port.

Better is to create a stored session in PuTTY (with the custom port) matching name of WinSCP stored site. WinSCP, then instead of using its own configuration, instructs PuTTY to open that same-named session.

See https://winscp.net/eng/docs/integration_putty#session_configuration

Answer (score 0):

ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -P xxx 
in windows cmd :
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" -ssh root@xxx.xx.xxx.xx -P xxx